# Bootstrap 4 table hover color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm struggling to change the hover color in a Bootstrap **4.1** table, using the sandstone theme, my current code does not affect the color of hovered rows:

```
<head>  
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.1.0/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >        

<style type="text/css">
    table.table-hover tbody tr.table-active td {
         background-color: #fb9692;
    }               
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="table-responsive" id="filesTable">
    <script id="filesTmpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr class="text-center" style="font-weight: bold;">
                <th scope="col">Filename</th>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                <th scope="col">Submitted on</th>               
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbod">
        {{#.}}
            <tr class="text-center">                
                <td class="text-left">{{this.originalFilename}}</td>
                <td>{{this.status}}</td>
                <td>{{this.submissionDate}}</td>                
            </tr>
        {{/.}}      
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </script>
</div>
</body>
```

But the background color displays fine if I manually add the "table-active" class to the :

```
<tbody id="tbod">
     <tr class="text-center table-active">              
          <td>...</td>      
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

What am I doing wrong?! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking. You want to change color of a row when you hover over it? If so, just add :hover.
`table.table-hover tbody tr td:hover {
    background-color: #fb9692;
}`

Comment: That did it (actually tr:hover), the type of mishap that happens when you don't do css for too long. Please post an answer so I can accept, thanks.

Comment: Great! It was just a minor mistake. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add :hover to your td.

```
table.table-hover tbody tr td:hover {
    background-color: #fb9692; 
}
```